# ajax with JavaScript exception: unexpected end of input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I have an input field for a concept and when the user fills it out, he has to then check if the concept exists. So I made a check button, which checks a database using ajax and JavaScript to see if the concept exists. My problem is when using ajax and JavaScript I get this exception:

> unexpected end of input

**JS :**

```
var concept = document.getElementById('acConceptName').value;
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            var isexisted = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            if(isexisted[0]==true){
                var errorMessage = document.getElementById('acSuggesConcepts');
                var p = document.createElement('p');
                p.innerHTML="this concept is already existed";
                errorMessage.appendChild(p);
                errorMessage.style.display="block";            
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/Mar7ba/Ontology/isExistedConcept/"+concept+"/TRUE",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

What is the exception and how can I solve it ?

**PHP :** function to check database and I always return true in it

```
public function isExistedConcept($concpetName,$Ajax){
        if($Ajax==true){
            $results=true
             $d=array($results);
            return json_encode($d);
        }
 }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Wiliam_Kinaan/s7Srx/2/

Comment: i got the error after var isexisted

Comment: @Slaks there is a demo , if u have time check the error , thank you

Comment: I suspect your problem is coming from the PHP side.. Possibly an error being printed that is messing up the encoding of the JSON... You should use chrome or firefox to follow the AJAX call and see the raw return data.

Comment: @Lix ok i will do but please how to tell chrome to give me AJAX returnd data and thank you

Comment: Hit `F12` and go to the `console` tab.  Right click anywhere in there and make sure that `Log XMLHttpRequests` is on.  Then make the AJAX call. You'll see that you can click on it and it should take you to the network tab... from there click again on the AJAX call and you should see some raw data there with some *additional smaller tabs*... go to the `response` tab... That is the raw response data that you got back from the AJAX call...

Comment: @Lix i did as u said , but there is no response tab , there is these tabs Method , status ,Type, iniiator, Size, Time,TimeLine

Comment: [this is what I'm talking about](http://i.imgur.com/ZabUR.png)

Comment: @Lix yes i found it :) , and google chrome print his to my ajax " This request has no response data available" , and i added return to my php code like this 
 if ($Ajax) {
            
            return "1";
        }else
            return "2";
and i print in js the returned data but the result was empty

Comment: Are you `echo`ing the value returned from `isExistedConcept`? Just returning it is not enough...

Comment: @Lix i just didn't return anything in my php , just echo "1" and it works :) :) :) , no it is working , but the solution was not good , plesae what shoud i do to make php return and not echo , thank you man

Comment: That is what you want the PHP to do... You want it to echo a string that is in the the JSON format - `{'index':'value'}`.  That is what the `json_encode($d)` value is for - you'll want your PHP to echo out that string and that is what the return value will be.

Comment: @Lix ok i understand that  , really i didn't know what is json_encode :) :) , but now i make php code like this 
$results = array("1");
            return json_encode($results);
but the google chrome prints nothing :(

Comment: See my answer below - I think the problem is that you are using `return`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the code for a while, one thing that might be a suspect is your PHP.

Your function in php ends with a `return` command.  What the AJAX call is actually waiting for is some data to be sent back. The return command simply passes that value back to the entity that originally called the function.

Try alter your function to `echo` the result as opposed to returning it.  Save your return value for when you need the result to go into another PHP function, not when you are returning data to the client.
I only put this return command here for readability.

```
public function isExistedConcept($concpetName,$Ajax){
  if($Ajax==true){
    $results=true
    $d=array($results);
    echo json_encode($d);
  }
  return;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function isExistedConcept($concpetName,$Ajax) {
    if( $Ajax) return "1";
}
// This is a simplified version of what you're doing, but it returns "1" instead of "[true]"
// Now for the JS:

if( xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    var isexisted = xmlhttp.responseText == "1";
    if( isexisted) {...}
```

If that doesn't work, try adding `alert(xmlhttp.responseText)` and see if you're getting anything other than what should be there.

Comment: i did as what u said , and after var isexisted = ..... i alter(isexisted) and the result was false

Comment: You didn't `alert` what I told you to `alert`.

Comment: i alter xmlhttp.status after the var isexsited.... and the result was empty , i mean nothing

Comment: Did you ever actually `echo` the result of `isExistedConcept`? It would probably be useful to see where you are calling it.

Comment: i echo it and the result is "1" becuase i return "1"

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var concept = document.getElementById('acConceptName').value;
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/Mar7ba/Ontology/isExistedConcept/"+concept+"/TRUE",true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){
            if(xmlhttp.status==200){
                var isexisted = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                if(isexisted[0]==true){
                    var errorMessage = document.getElementById('acSuggesConcepts');
                    var p = document.createElement('p');
                    p.innerHTML="this concept is already existed";
                    errorMessage.appendChild(p);
                    errorMessage.style.display="block";            
                }
                    else{ 
                        console.log('error');
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Comment: still the same , and i alter xmlhttp.repsontext after var isexisted. .. and the result was empty

Comment: yes i tried it already and seems that it doesn't reach the if(200) cos the else doesn't print anything

Comment: okay i have modified the code, before onreadystatechange, i put xmlhttp.open. it may work. check.

Comment: then there is a mistake in 

 if(isexisted[0]==true){
                    var errorMessage = document.getElementById('acSuggesConcepts');
                    var p = document.createElement('p');
                    p.innerHTML="this concept is already existed";
                    errorMessage.appendChild(p);
                    errorMessage.style.display="block";            
                }
block. check it.

Comment: first i change my php code to this <code>if($Ajax){
            //$results=$this->model->isExistedConcept($concpetName);
           // $results = array(true);
            //return json_encode($results);
            return "1";
        }</code>
and my js code to this http://jsfiddle.net/Wiliam_Kinaan/s7Srx/5/
now as u said the else statement works , see it please

Comment: i think your xmlhttp.responseText is not returning the data which your expecting, so add console.log(xmlhttp.responseText); after if(xmlhttp.status==200){ . then try

Comment: ok i did and it prints nothing , please would you check my update 
http://jsfiddle.net/Wiliam_Kinaan/s7Srx/5/
now the else statement not working , that mean the php code return false and not true , but see my php code in my last tow comments i update it to return "1" and in my js i check it "1"

Comment: btw how are you running that script? by putting everything on webroot?